# $L^p$ Norm of product of two bounded functions

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions in $L^p[a,b]$, does the following inequality hold in $L_p$ spaces?

$$\|fg\|_p\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_p$$

Comment: No. Counterexample for $p=1$: let $f(x) = g(x) = x$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then $\|fg\|_1 = 1/3$ whereas $\|f\|_1 \|g\|_1 = 1/4$.

Comment: is there any possibility for$ L^2[a,b]$?

Comment: Again using $f(x) = g(x) = x$ on the interval $[0,1]$, we have $\|fg\|_2 = 1/\sqrt{5}$, whereas $\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 = 1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon$ be smaller than $\min\{b-a,1\}$ and $f(x)=g(x):=\mathbf 1_{[a,a+\varepsilon]}(x)$. Then 
$$\lVert fg\rVert_p=\left(\int_{[a,b]}\mathbf 1_{[a,a+\varepsilon]}(x)\right)^{1/p}=\varepsilon^{1/p}$$
and 
$$\lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_p=\varepsilon^{2/p}.$$